# How to click an element if another one can't be located

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to execute the following instructions:

I search an element with the following code

```
ipokay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

But I want that if this element is not found (returns the error 'unable to locate element') the script should click the element with another class, for example "btn-new btn-wide"

how to do that?

Comment: Post the HTML of the main and alternate tags that you want to look for.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is it same button with 2 different class names or do you want click button B if button A does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a try/except block.

```
try:
    ipokay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    ipokay = driver.find_element_by_some_other_way("something").click()
```

Comment: NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined

Comment: You'll have to import that exception from the selenium module.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in a try/except block like John Gordon said.
Or you can use `find_elements_` instead of `find_element_` and check the list size. That way you can avoid handling the exception and it is faster than waiting for the exception.

```py
ipokays = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")

if len(ipokays) > 0 :
    ipokays.index(0).click()
else :
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn-new btn-wide']").click()
```

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='.btn-new.btn-wide']"}

Comment: In xpath, you shouldn't use `.` like CSS selector and use the full class value shown in dev tool. You can change the selector to CSS selector and use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn-new.btn-wide')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to click element with multiple element location options. You can send any number of different element locators. It will try one by one.

Eg: click(By.xpath("path"), By.id("id"), By.name("name));

```java
public static void click(By... by){
    int count=by.length;
    for(By locator:by){
        if(isElementPresent(locator)) {
            getDriver().findElement(locator).click();
            break;
        }
        count--;
    }
    if(count<0)
        assertTrue(false,"Count not find element.");
}

public static boolean isElementPresent(By selector)
{
    try {
        driver.findElement(selector);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
    }
}
```